# Start script when new element on directory

Tags: python

I want to convert every new wav file coming into an input dir to another dir on mp3. I've been look how to convert those file but, I don't know how to add a listener on the input dir or if it's even possible?

Edit:
Sorry, I've forget to share you the code I already have. I use ffmpeg to convert audio file

```
import os, sys, glob

FFMPEG_PATH = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin"

fileName = ""
fileExt = ""

wavdir = ""
mp3dir = ""


for file in glob.glob('wav/*.wav'):

    # get the name  without .ext
    fileName = os.path.basename(file)
    fileName = fileName.split(".")[0]

    # verify if no mp3 file with thesame name exist
    if not os.path.isfile('./mp3/'+fileName+".mp3"):

        # set var with the 2 types files dir
        wavdir = file
        mp3dir = "mp3/"+fileName+".mp3"

        # start the convertion with ffmpeg by commande line
        os.system("ffmpeg -i "+wavdir+" "+mp3dir)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What OS are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could program a script to monitor the folder for changes and convert automatically, but you'll need to start writing something, googling a little bit, and come here when you have specific issues and problems that you are stuck with

Comment: This link provides some good stuff on directory changes. http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best idea, however you can assign a process or a thread to check if a file was added to the directory every X seconds:

```
import os
import time
wav_files_path = "/WAV_dir_path"
prev_files = os.listdir(wav_files_path)
x = 1 # time to sleep
while True:
    files = os.listdir(wav_files_path)
    if len(files) > len(prev_files):  # if files are not deleted it's better to check if any files were added
        # NEW FILE(S) ADDED
        for f in files:
            if f not in prev_files:
                convert_file(f)
    prev_files = files
    time.sleep(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is highly suboptimal, but should do the job

```
import os, time

SLEEPTIME = 0.5
TARGET_DIRECTORY = 'path_of_your_folder'

while True:
    time.sleep(SLEEPTIME)
    files = os.listdir(TARGET_DIRECTORY)
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.wav'):
            CONVERT
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a `while True` loop. Then in the loop you make another loop with `for item in os.listdir(yourdir)` in there you move every item and then you can make `time.sleep(1)` to reduce lag.